# How to show span/label text into select tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I'm trying to show the text "sesso" on the left side of the dropdown select. This is what I did but it doesn't work. I put span tag inside select tag.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/7L168ws2/32/

```css
input[type="text"]:not(.browser-default){
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.caret {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.select-wrapper input.select-dropdown {
 padding-right: 15px!important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://motustrength.it/MDB4.19.1-PRO/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://motustrength.it/MDB4.19.1-PRO/css/mdb.min.css">

  <!-- Start your project here-->  
<div class="prov">
  <select class="mdb-select" id="inputGroupSelect03" > 
    <span class="input-group-tex">Sesso</span>
    <option class="seleziona" selected value="0">Seleziona</option>
    <option id="sexuomo" name="radios" value="Male"  required class="sexbtn">Uomo</option>
    <option id="sexdonna" name="radios" value="Female" form="bmrcalc" required class="sexbtn">Donna</option>
  </select>
</div>  
  <!-- End your project here-->

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://motustrength.it/MDB4.19.1-PRO/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://motustrength.it/MDB4.19.1-PRO/js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://motustrength.it/MDB4.19.1-PRO/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://motustrength.it/MDB4.19.1-PRO/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can't. `span` is not a valid child of `select`.

Comment: Why you don't show as title outside the select?

Comment: When span is out of select this is not shown next to the word seleziona, but rather above, outside the box and not horizontally aligned with the dropdown. Sorry for the ignorance, but I'm a fan.

Comment: What I'm trying to get is a dropdown with the label or span on the left, in short, something that indicates the title of the field, while on the right the button that allows the action to open the dropdown. Example: https://ibb.co/WfV3Y6x

Comment: Put it outside the select, and position it absolute ...? https://jsfiddle.net/2jvrsdcx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know you meant this, but hope it could help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/GeorgeLXL/spLgbutv/1/

```js
// Material Select Initialization
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.mdb-select').materialSelect();
});
```

```css
input[type="text"]:not(.browser-default){
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.caret {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.select-wrapper input.select-dropdown {
 padding-right: 15px!important;
}

.input-group-tex {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.prov {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.2/css/all.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://motustrength.it/MDB4.19.1-PRO/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://motustrength.it/MDB4.19.1-PRO/css/mdb.min.css">

  <!-- Start your project here-->  
<div class="prov">
  <span class="input-group-tex">Sesso</span>
  <select class="mdb-select" id="inputGroupSelect03" > 
    <option class="seleziona" selected value="0">Seleziona</option>
    <option id="sexuomo" name="radios" value="Male"  required class="sexbtn">Uomo</option>
    <option id="sexdonna" name="radios" value="Female" form="bmrcalc" required class="sexbtn">Donna</option>
  </select>
</div>  
  <!-- End your project here-->

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://motustrength.it/MDB4.19.1-PRO/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://motustrength.it/MDB4.19.1-PRO/js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://motustrength.it/MDB4.19.1-PRO/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://motustrength.it/MDB4.19.1-PRO/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is the result I was looking for.